# How to catch http response code in RxJS subscribe() angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have this method inside service code.

list.service.ts

```
public getList(id: string): Observable<ListData> {
  const url = this.config.getUrl + '/${id}'
  return this.http.get<ListData>(url);
}
```

and I'm trying to catch response code from this method and have user-friendly message on any error inside the component.

app.component.ts

```
public ngOnInit() {
  this.isWaiting = true;
  const id = 'testid'
  this.service.getList(id).pipe(
    finalize(() => this.isWaiting = false)
  ).subscribe(
    listData => //do something with success result,
    error => {   --------------------  error.status does not contain response code.
       if (error.status === '403')
        { console.log("You're not authorized") }
       else if (error.status === '500')
        { console.log("Something wrong!!") } 
       ....
       etc...

    }
  );
 }
```

But error.status is not returning anything here. Is there a proper way to catch http status code in this case?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

`error.status` is a `number`.

You're comparing a `number` with a `string` using the strict equality operator (`===`).
Obviously, this comparison will always fail as the types are different.

```
403 === '403'  // false
403 ==  '403'  // true
```

Either compare `error.status` with a `number`, or use the abstract equality operator (`==`).

```
if (error.status === 403)
// or
if (error.status == '403')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer here in terms of the problem, but I would advise against changing to `==` operators. You should almost exclusively stick with `===`. Another thing, if you for some reason NEED the status code you're comparing to to be a string, you can do `String(error.status) === '403'`.

Comment: He states that status code returns nothing. So this is more of a comment than an answer. I got the same problem with nothing being returned in the status code (0). Works in postman